# NSUserDefaults, Settings.bundle and App groups

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have an app with 2 targets, the main app and a Today extension - to share settings between these targets I've switched on the App Groups Capabilities, added a group `group.myApp.com` and then using `NSUserDefaults` like so in both the main app and Today Extension:

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myApp.com")!
```

(following the instructions here: http://goo.gl/pNrYQl)

This is working fine. I would like to add a Settings.bundle to the app to change settings in both targets but this seems to be using the `standardUserDefaults` for the 'main' target, not the `group.myApp.com` section. Any ideas how to make the Settings.bundle use my `group.myApp.com` settings 'area'?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Eventually found the answer in the comments section of the original [linked](http://tapadoo.com/2014/sharing-nsuserdefaults-between-your-app-and-a-today-extension-on-ios-8/) website.

> to target App-Group settings instead of the App Targets user defaults,
>   all you need to do is add “ApplicationGroupContainerIdentifier” as a
>   key to the Root.plist of your Settings Bundle and set its value as
>   your App-Group identifier

So, after adding the following to my Settings.Bundle Root.plist, both my main App and Today Extension are accessing the same user defaults.

[image]