# Settings bundle for a standalone iMessage app

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, imessage-extension

I'm working on a standalone iMessage app that has some user preferences that we expect will be rarely changed.

I was hoping to put these in a settings bundle so they could be accessed if needed via the settings.app, but after adding the bundle, the iMessage app doesn't appear as an option within the settings app.

[Apples guide states](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW18):

> When the Settings app launches, it checks each custom app for the presence of a Settings bundle. For each custom bundle it finds, it loads that bundle and displays the corresponding app’s name and icon in the Settings main page. When the user taps the row belonging to your app, Settings loads the Root.plist Settings page file for your Settings bundle and uses that file to build your app’s main page of preferences.

I've tried adding a Settings.bundle to both project targets, and tried setting up an app group ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29220186/1060154)) but no luck.

Since iOS 8, the settings app will show a listing for your app if it had requested permissions (location, notifications, camera etc) so I've even tried having the iMessage app use current location just to see if that would trigger an item in the settings.app, but that also didn't work.

Is there something else I can try, or can anyone confirm that stand alone iMessage apps can't have a settings bundle?

Comment: Same question as you, did you ever find an official answer for this?

Comment: I didn't find a way to do this, but I also never found documentation saying it's not possible. In the end we shipped the app with a settings screen built into the UI